# Algorithm Efficiency for Nested For/If Loops in R

Tags: r, performance, algorithm, if-statement, for-loop

This is my first post on SO, so I apologize if this question has been asked somewhere else, but I can't seem to figure out how to even phrase my question so it's difficult to look.

The issue I'm having is that I'm working with a data frame which contains a variable, which is a factor, called PrimaryType. This variable has like 15 levels and I want to create new binary variables off of this so that I can perform statistical analyses on the various levels. Here is the code I'm using:

```
df <- read.csv('Data/ChiCrime11_13.txt', header=T, sep='\t')

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for (crimes in levels(df$PrimaryType)){
    if (df$PrimaryType == crimes) {
      df[crimes] <- 1
    }
    else{
      df[crimes] <- 0
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my data frame is over 900,000 observations long and so clearly this process is going to take a LOT of time to run (900,000^15 iterations I believe). This brings me to my question: Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Any thoughts/advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: not 900,000^15, but 900,000*15, which is a lot but not undoable.

Comment: You could use multiple threads and give to each of them a part of the data to calculate

Comment: @igelineau Multiple threading is foreign to me at the moment. I'm interested in learning how to do it, but I wouldn't even know where to start right now.

Comment: You should start by initializing your data frame ahead of time with the right number of rows. Adding rows as you go takes up much more time Also you could initialize all of the values to zero and then eliminate the `else` part of your code. Otherwise it would help to see a few lines of the data.

Comment: Also, are you sure the code gives you what you want?  I don't think it matches your description, as you're never using `i`.  It would be good to clarify which of your code or your description is correct, or (also possible) if I'm just out to lunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might be faster

```
for (crimes in levels(df$PrimaryType)){
    df[,crimes] <- ifelse (df$PrimaryType == crimes, 1, 0)
}
```

It would be faster still if you just create all of your variables with zeroes and then just assigned the ones.

```
df[, levels(df$PrimaryType)] <- 0
for (crimes in levels(df$PrimaryType)){
    df[df$PrimaryType == crimes,crimes] <- 1
}
```

You should look for questions on optimizing and vector operations in R next time you're stuck on something like this..

Comment: +1 - maybe just `df[,crimes] <- as.integer(df$PrimaryType == crimes)` in that first one.

Comment: And for the second one, you can do `df[, levels(df$PrimaryType)][cbind(seq(nrow(df)), df$PrimaryType)] <- 1` instead of the loop.

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of options and I was trying to make a compromise between transparency in the code and efficiency. Any one of these will run many times faster than the original.

Comment: I prefer this option over the option that Aaron presented because it keeps the variables in the data frame I've already created. It's absurd how much faster this than the approach I tried. My method ran over night and never finished. This method ran in under 3 minutes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `df <- cbind(df, model.matrix(~0+PrimaryType, data=df))`?

Comment: I think you end up with a data frame where the last X columns will be a matrix. That's find as long as you know how to access that but it won't be obvious from just looking at it. You'd need syntax like df$mat[,1] to get the first column of where the matrix starts. If you cast the matrix to data.frame before binding then it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

First, what kind of statistical analysis?  Many functions (such as `lm`) take factors directly and there's no need to create your own dummy variables.

If you do really need to create your own, `R` has a function to do this, as below.  I don't know how fast it will be on such a big data set, but I'd try it first before writing your own code.

```
model.matrix(~0+PrimaryType, data=df)
```

Example usage and output:

```
> foo <- data.frame(x=factor(LETTERS[1:5]))
> model.matrix(~0+x, data=foo)
  xA xB xC xD xE
1  1  0  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  0
5  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: +1 - dammit I wish I scrolled down a little. I just wrote this up to. :-)

Comment: @user2789863 be careful because this results in a matrix, not a data.frame, so it has different name access rules. Also, when you use this, or these variables, in some statistical procedures it will have specified behaviour based on the additional attributes assigned to the matrix. That's all easily fixed by changing the type but it's just a word of caution. Otherwise, this is the simplest and possibly fastest answer.